# Why Python matches a list as a tuple?

Tags: python, list, tuples, pattern-matching, python-3.10

With Python 3.11.0a2+, and the following code:

```py
def my_fun(e):
    match e:
        case (1,):
            print("tuple (1,)")
        case [1]:
            print("list [1]")
        case _:
            print("I don't understand")
```

Calling the function with `my_fun([1])` prints "tuple (1,)".

Is this behavior correct?

If I explicitly match against `tuple((1, ))` instead of `(1,)`, it works as expected.

If this is not a bug of the interpreter, what is the reason behind this seemingly weird behavior?

Comment: The `type` function will return different values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [documented under *Structural Pattern Matching*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#other-key-features)

> Like unpacking assignments, **tuple and list patterns have exactly the
> same meaning and actually match arbitrary sequences**. Technically, the
> subject must be a sequence. Therefore, an important exception is that
> patterns don’t match iterators. Also, to prevent a common mistake,
> sequence patterns don’t match strings.

and in [PEP 635 -- Structural Pattern Matching: Motivation and Rationale](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0635/#sequence-patterns)

> **As in iterable unpacking, we do not distinguish between '*tuple*' and
> '*list*' notation. `[a, b, c]`, `(a, b, c)` and `a, b, c` are all equivalent.**
> While this means we have a redundant notation and checking
> specifically for lists or tuples requires more effort (e.g. case
> `list([a, b, c]))`, we mimic iterable unpacking as much as possible.